# Earth Engine -- Single US Image w/out Clouds

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm working on a project about US Census data and satellite images, and would like to use earth engine. In a number of the snippets I found online, a number of images from a collection are selected and the one with the fewest clouds is used.

Is there a single cloudless (stitched together) image of the US I can use within Earth Engine?

I plan on extracting images of each US Census block, and I fear that doing this computation for each block will result in long runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is a bit light on details, so I won't be able to give you much details. There are a few global Landsat 8, greenest pixel composites in the EE catalog that you could use.

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_ANNUAL_GREENEST_TOA')
  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2018-01-01')
  .first()
  .multiply(10000)
  .int16()
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', min: 300, max: 3000, gamma: 1.3})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1fce221a95f03b89a608146532284d53

But you probably better off creating one or more custom median composites.